# Simple Type and Erase Effect Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple type and erase effect using javascript, however, after the typing effect, it deletes the last letter and then I get an endless screen of undefined.  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Typing Effect</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


window.onload =function() {
var texttotype = "this is what i want to type";
var typedtext = "";

function eraze(){

if(typedtext != ""){            
    var eraze = setInterval(function(){ 
        typedtext = typedtext.slice(0, typedtext.length -1);                    
        document.getElementById('type-here').innerHTML = typedtext;
            if (typedtext == "") {
              clearInterval(eraze);
              return
            }               
        }, 200);        
}   
}   

if(typedtext == ""){
    var i = 0;
    var id = setInterval(function(){
        if(typedtext != texttotype){
            typedtext +=texttotype[i];
        document.getElementById('type-here').innerHTML = typedtext;
        } else if (typedtext == texttotype) {
            eraze();                          
        }
        i++;        
    }, 200);            
}

}
</script>

<p id="type-here"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

BTW, Each piece of the code individually works, The typing types and the erase erases, I just cant get it to type then eraze. Any direction or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!!

Comment: derloopkat I wanted to create an infinite type erase effect, this is why I didn't put a stop to the write function. nevertheless, what you suggest fixes the problem that it now lets me eraze the text. Any idea how to make this an ifinite write eraze? A while(true) loop doesn't seem to work, it hangs my browser. Thanks!!!

Comment: I have updated the solution to type and erase forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to stop the function that writes text after all the text is already written. Otherwise it will go beyond the end of the string and add "undefined" to the page.

```
window.onload = function () {
var texttotype = "this is what i want to type";
var typedtext = "";

function eraze() {

    if (typedtext != "") {
        var eraze = setInterval(function () {
            typedtext = typedtext.slice(0, typedtext.length - 1);
            document.getElementById('type-here').innerHTML = typedtext;
            if (typedtext == "") { //all done
                clearInterval(eraze);
                write();
                return
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}
function write() {
    if (typedtext == "") {
        var i = 0;
        var keepWriting = setInterval(function () {
            if (typedtext != texttotype) {
                typedtext += texttotype[i];
                document.getElementById('type-here').innerHTML = typedtext;
            } else if (typedtext == texttotype) {
                clearInterval(keepWriting);
                eraze();
                return;
            }
            i++;
        }, 200);
    }
}
write();
}
```

Comment: derloopkat I wanted to create an infinite type erase effect, this is why I didn't put a stop to the write function. nevertheless, what you suggest fixes the problem that it now lets me eraze the text. Any idea how to make this an ifinite write eraze? A while(true) loop doesn't seem to work, it hangs my browser. Thanks!!

Comment: I have updated the solution. This will write and erase forever. Now, write function start writing from the beginning whereas keepWriting continues from the last written character. The first thing that happens when the page is loaded functions are declared and write() is executed.